# All the values from FirebaseDatabase are not getting assigned to long even in FastAdapter's bindView()

Tags: java, android, menuitem, instanceof, fastadapter

I'm trying to filter the content from `FirebaseDatabase` based on time and for that I have created a method and am calling it from the `FastAdapter`'s `bindView()` of the `RecyclerView`.

I'm subtracting currentTime from the startTime using this code:

```
holder.now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
holder.startTimeDateInEpochLong = Long.parseLong(holder.startDateTimeInEpoch.getText().toString());
holder.diff = holder.startTimeDateInEpochLong - holder.now;
Log.d("log1", String.valueOf(holder.diff));
```

and then using the `holder.diff` to do the logic in the method of the `MainActivity` and calling that method from the `bindView()` like this:

```
MainActivity.filterButton.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if(holder.mContext instanceof MainActivity){
                    ((MainActivity)holder.mContext).filterRequests(holder.diff);
                    Log.d("log2", String.valueOf(holder.diff));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The problem is that `log1` shows all the values of `holder.diff` but `log2` shows only the last fetched value and do the logic using it only.

How can I make sure that `.filterRequests(holder.diff)` do the logic using all the values of `holder.diff`?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TimeStamp data type rather than long. Hope it will work.